# Twitter Stream API, Parameter follow has unparseable items

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, pycurl

Recently I'm doing a small project on twitter, and I want to get tweets from some specific users.

So I use `Streaming API`, `pycurl` and `python`.

The API Reference says the `follow` parameter is:

> A comma separated list of user IDs, indicating the users to return
>   statuses for in the stream. See the follow parameter documentation for
>   more information.

And I tried this

```
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, 'follow=slaindev')
```

but the return message is not the tweets that `slaindev` posted, but an error

> Parameter follow has unparseable items slaindev

So do I misunderstand the meaning of user ID? I think it is the one we use to mention someone( I mean I use @slaindev to mention this guy).

When I try track parameter, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption regarding user_id is incorrect. See [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup), for example. You are talking about screen_name.